# The do loop is executed indefinitely

Tags: java

```
do
            {
                Long time = startTime.getTime()+(((59*60)+59)*1000);
                Date endTime = new Date(time); 
                System.out.println("INFO:   Calling startWork("+startTime+","+endTime+")");

                startWork(startTime,endTime);
                System.out.println("Info ");
                startTime = new Date (startTime.getTime()+(60*60*1000));
                systemHour = new Date(new Date().getYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate(),new Date().getHours(),0,0);
                String stringToUpdateLastProcessedTime = "update meter_thread set last_processed_time='"+sdf.format(startTime)+"' where name='Kochi Occupancy' ";
                mysqlStatement.executeUpdate(stringToUpdateLastProcessedTime);  

            }while(startTime.getTime()!= systemHour.getTime());
```

The last processed time is taken from the database table , and could be any time before the present time and is updated after every data fetch .

The above code should stop after the while loop is true , but it doesn't .where is the problem in the code ??

Comment: the condition probably is never false ;) Which is quite easy when you compare two times with !=

Comment: What is systemHour.getTime() supposed to represent, I was expecting a construct along the lines of currentTime<endTime but this doesn't look like that

Comment: What do i do if i need my code to stop when the time is in 1 hour block of current time . like if the time is 12:30 . it should stop if the starttime is in between 11:31 to 12:30 .

Comment: @user1896796 Why is startTime in the condition at all? Surely only currentTime and endTime are important?

Answer (score 4):

The condition is an exact one:

```
startTime.getTime()!= systemHour.getTime()
```

If the loop missed the end time, by even the smallest unit it will continue forever.

You want something that has a true side (eg all the way to -infinity) and a false side (eg all the way to positive infinity) so;

```
startTime.getTime()<= systemHour.getTime()
```

or

```
startTime.getTime()>= systemHour.getTime()
```

Depending on the logic of your program

### Usage of start time in the condition

I've included the condition both ways in the last section because the logic seems unclear. I would expect a condition that looked like

```
currentTime.getTime()<=endTime.getTime()
```

Such that it asks the question "is the current time less than the time when we end the loop". Where endTime is calculated however you see fit when the loop starts (e.g. 1 hour from now)